# How to convert unique_ptr<derived>* to unique_ptr<base>*?

Tags: c++, c++17

I've got 4 classes, `base`, `base_collection` and `derived::base`, `derived_collection::base_collection`;

In `base_collection` there is a constructor with signature:

```
base_collection(unique_ptr<base> *begin, unique_ptr<base> *end)
```

In `derived_collection` there is a constructor with signature:

```
derived_collection (unique_ptr<derived> *begin, unique_ptr<derived> *end)
```

And obviously I want to implement it as

```
derived_collection (unique_ptr<derived> *begin, unique_ptr<derived> *end) :
  base_collection(something(begin), something(end)) {}
```

But I'm struggling with the `something`. I guess its a custom iterator, but my attempts so far have failed as it keeps telling me that my custom iterator isn't convertible to `unique_ptr<base> *begin`. I'm not really bothered at this point as to whether what I'm doing is a good idea or not, I'm just keen to know how to get this working.

I'm using C++17.

**EDIT**

To give some context `unique_ptr<base> *base` is an iterator, not necessarily a pointer. The `base_collection` constructor iterates from `begin` to `end`.

What I want to do is iterate over a derived collection via begin / end iterators that the compiler sees as base iterators.

`something` is exactly that. I'm not sure what needs to be done to `begin` and `end` to make the compiler happy.

**UPDATE**

Alas someone who hadn't read the comments or didn't understand them decided to hide them all, however it seems like what I was attempting to do was either impossible or close to impossible and the conclusion was that a different approach was needed.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215673/discussion-on-question-by-satnhak-how-to-convert-unique-ptrderived-to-unique).

Answer (score 1):

`std::unique_ptr<Base>*` cannot be converted `std::unique_ptr<Derived>*` because they are unrelated classes, even though template argument `Derived` derives from `Base` publicly.

To solve your problem, you need another level of indirection. E.g., a special iterator type that double-dereferences `unique_ptr<Base>*` and down-casts `Base&` to `Derived&` in `Iter::operator*` and `Iter::operator[]`, and `Base*` to `Derived*` in `Iter::operator->`. You can create such an iterator from scratch, but that's a lot of boiler-plate code typing, or use [`boost::iterator_facade`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_facade.html) that implements that boiler-plate code for you.

So, you'd have `Iter<Base, unique_ptr<Base>*>` and `Iter<Derived, unique_ptr<Base>*>` and they must be convertible to each other, as long as the second template arguments match. And then:

```
base_collection(Iter<Base, unique_ptr<Base>*> begin, Iter<Base, unique_ptr<Base>*> end);

derived_collection(Iter<Derived, unique_ptr<Base>*> begin, Iter<Derived, unique_ptr<Base>*> end) :
  base_collection(begin, end) {} // Implicit conversion Iter<Derived, unique_ptr<Base>*> -> Iter<Base, unique_ptr<Base>*>.
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd assumed I needed an intermediary iterator and had built one with boost::iterator_facade, but I couldn't get it working. Now it seems that I was being too ambitious as I wanted to preserve the `base* ` signature.